# Using T-SQL can I create 100 average prices (like Excel PERCENTILE) from six months of sales data ranked lowest to highest?

Tags: t-sql, ranking, percentile

I have 15,000 sales from 1st Oct 2019 to 31st Mar 2020, the data is as follows;

```
Edate         CustomerNo    ProductType     SaleSource      SalePrice
2020-02-15    276495        Classic         ONLINE          706.66
2019-11-06    218943        Modern          OFFLINE         206.35
2019-12-27    228735        FClassic        OFFLINE         97.54
2020-01-17    271957        Vintage         ONLINE          150.84
```

And so on for c.15k rows of sales.

I need to take all these prices and show a ranking of the lowest to highest price our customers have paid on average for ***the entire date period***. The ranking needs to be from 1 (lowest price) to 100 (highest price) and will be;

1. Per Sale source
2. Overall regardless of sale source
3. And then per product type within the first two

Very much as the Excel PERCENTILE function might do (only I can't do this in Excel).

An example of the final result needed would be as follows (but going all the way down to P_100)

[image: Percentile Example]

I'm hoping T-SQL can do the work so I can easily insert the results into a simple SSRS report for subscription and self serve.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/avg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Looks like this page might have info you need.

Comment: I don't think that will work @feyd my data would have to already have something in it that represented the 100 segments for partitioning and it doesn't. I need to force 100 averages out of this where no column exists to represent a partition value.

Comment: T-SQL has percentile functions, check out [PERCENTILE_CONT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/percentile-cont-transact-sql), [PERCENTILE_DISC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/percentile-disc-transact-sql) and [PERCENT_RANK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/percent-rank-transact-sql). Combining it with [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot) should go a long way to your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this.

```
WITH Student
       AS (SELECT Marks
           FROM(VALUES(75), (59), (69), (88), (72), (86), (60), (67), (49), (81), (93),(NULL)) Val(Marks)),
       Percentiles
       AS (SELECT Marks, 
                  PERCENT_RANK() OVER(
                  ORDER BY Marks) AS Percent_Rank
           FROM Student)
       SELECT *
       FROM Percentiles
```

[image]

I can't see the image that you posted, but change the field named 'Marks' to the field that you want to do the ranking on, and you should be good to go.